# Для чего нужны атрибуты ComVisible и DispId?

Tags: .net, windows, com

Хочу спросить насчет интерфейса `IEnumerable`, который как я понял используется при работе с коллекциями(я их только начал изучать), но тема не о коллекциях, а о содержимом вышеупомянутого интерфейса:

```
namespace System.Collections
{
    // Сводка:
    //     Предоставляет перечислитель, который поддерживает простой перебор элементов
    //     неуниверсальной коллекции.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("496B0ABE-CDEE-11d3-88E8-00902754C43A")]
    public interface IEnumerable
    {
        // Сводка:
        //     Возвращает перечислитель, осуществляющий итерацию в коллекции.
        //
        // Возвращает:
        //     Объект System.Collections.IEnumerator, который может использоваться для перебора
        //     коллекции.
        [DispId(-4)]
        IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Итак, по порядку, что мне не понятно:
строка

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```

как дает определение Visual Studio, когда навожу курсор настроку:
** class System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute
Управляет доступгостьб отдельног управляемого типа или члена или всех типов в сборке для COM **
Итак, вопросы в студию:

```
InteropServices - ?
COM - это что вообще ?
ComVisibleAttribute - ?
что за ComVisible 

[ComVisible(true)]- какую роль он выполняет
```

Управляемый тип\член ?

Далее:

```
[DispId(-4)]
```

Опять же, определение Visual Studio
** class System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispldAttribute
Задает идентификатор диспетчирезации COM(DISPID) для метода, поля или свойства. **

идентификатор диспетчирезации COM(DISPID) - что!?

диспетчирезация COM - ?

DISPID - ?

И значит захожу я в этот

```
[DispId(-4)]
```

А там вот такое:

```
public sealed class DispIdAttribute : Attribute
{
    // Сводка:
    //     Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса DispIdAttribute, используя указанный
    //     идентификатор DISPID.
    //
    // Параметры:
    //   dispId:
    //     Идентификатор DISPID для этого члена.
    public DispIdAttribute(int dispId);

    // Сводка:
    //     Возвращает идентификатор DISPID для члена.
    //
    // Возвращает:
    //     Идентификатор DISPID для этого члена.
    public int Value { get; }
}
```

и как я понял, этот

```
[DispId(-4)]
```

- это конструктор класса DispIdAttribute ?

Умоляю дать подробный и развернутый ответ, без вот этого : "там есть некие механизмы, но так как ты сейчас только начал учить коллекции, то тебе это будет не нужно и даже мешать" - поверьте, мне нужно все. Отвечать на вопросы можно, даже нужно так, что бы эти разрозненные вопросы в итоге сформировали один комплексный ответ.

Comment: Как насчет погуглить по поводу технологии COM в Windows? И того же Рихтера почитать ("Windows via C/C++").

Comment: можно даже в msdn сразу: [ComVisibleAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) и [DispIdAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @free_ze, вообще к IEnumerable вопрос имеет слабое отношение

Comment: [ответ на вопрос про DispId на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8892649/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy Согласен, я этому и не противоречил.

Comment: @free_ze, это я к правке заголовка, думал ты его поправил

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для начала, есть такая штука — [COM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) (почитайте про неё, есть много книг). Это стандарт для взаимодействия модулей на разных языках. Сборки C# также поддерживают этот стандарт по желанию (вы можете включить в свойствах сборки), так что .NET-объекты могут быть использованы как COM-объекты, и таким образом — различными нативными приложениями, а также скриптовыми языками (например, javascript).

Да, так `[ComVisible(true)]` означает, что интерфейс будет виден самой подсистеме COM, а значит, если *ваш* метод возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`, то его результатом можно воспользоваться при помощи COM.

Базовыми интерфейсами в COM являются [`IUnknown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509.aspx) и [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx). Последний из них особенно важен для скриптов, т. к. позволяет вызывать метод по строковому имени. `DispID` есть специальный атрибут для того, чтобы .NET мог сделать автоматическую имплементацию `IDispatch`.

---

Да, а если ваша программа не экспортирует COM-объекты, и не работает со скриптами, то скорее всего вам всё равно, и вы можете спокойно эти атрибуты игнорировать. Если ваша программа полностью на .NET, COM-атрибуты не важны для вас.

Answer (score 4):

Дам несколько частичный ответ

`[ComVisible(true)]` - Всё что в таких скобках перед классами, структурами, методами и атрибутами - это [дополнительные атрибуты](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.4.php) (Custom Attributes). Это прописано в языке C#.

Упрощенно можно сказать, что создается экземпляр класса атрибута при выполнении кода. Т.е. в вашем случае выполняется конструктор `ComVisible(true);`

Обратите внимание, что сам класс будет называться ComVisibleAttribute - т.е. с добавлением слова Attribute. Этого требует C#.

Технология COM -это такое средство взаимодействия  между программами и библиотеками написанными на самых разных языках. Технология большая сама по себе. Книги есть отдельные. Эти атрибуты класса ComVisibleAttribute как раз и управляют поведением взаимодействия между двумя программами, использующими COM технологию. Вообще dll в Винде написаны с помощью COM.

InteropServices - всего лишь пространство имен в котором содержится класс ComVisibleAttribute. Вы такое используете когда пишите namespace.

`[DispId(-4)]` вызовет конструктор класса `public sealed class DispIdAttribute : Attribute` с параметром -4. Реализация класса для вас скрыта, поэтому что там дальше посмотреть скорее всего не получится.

`[Guid("496B0ABE-CDEE-11d3-88E8-00902754C43A")]` - Это задает уникальный идентификатор. Он уникален вообще всегда.(теоретически и практически). Он служит для однозначного определения любых объектов.

Эти атрибуты вам не нужны. Рискуете зависнуть на очень долго. СОМ менялся много раз. Пока пропускайте их мимо.

Comment: *"Вообще dll в Винде написаны с помощью COM."* - да ну? :)

Comment: *Он уникален вообще всегда* лишь на практике. Но не в теории. Просто шанс коллизии на практике астрономически мал.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Представьте себе! ActiveX компоненты реализуют COM! Большая технология, различные применения. И конечно же можно dll и без COM создать. Пожалуй был не прав не написав слово некоторые dll  в винде используют COM

Comment: @PavelMayorov значительная часть dll - чуть более мягкое определение :)